# Windows Azure ACS with Windows Active Directory (2003)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, wif

Does anyone have any experience with this at all? I'm trying to link up my ACS with my companies local active directory, so obviously I'm going to need an STS that relates to this active directory for authentication/tokens.

Do I need to create my own custom STS or is there a tool out there somewhere that makes this simpler?

Any suggestions appreciated, hopefully someone's done this before.

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about this we have a book coming out soon on Claims Based Identity and have a few chapters on ACS with code. http://claimsid.codeplex.com. This has the chapters you can download now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACS is normally a Federation Provider. It doesn't have an underlying AD.

You need [Active Directory Federation Services 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/ad-fs-2-overview.aspx). This is an Identity Provider and sits on top of your local AD and federates with ACS.

(Note that ADFS can only authenticate against AD but can get attributes from AD, LDAP's and SQL Server for authorisation)

Comment: ADFS can also call arbitrary code for getting additional attributes (not just AD, SQL and LDAP). Technically, these attributes can be used for "anything" (including of course authorization, which is a very common use)