# How integrate active directory and sql azure for authenticating users to access the application running on azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I want to integrate on-premise active directory and sql azure for authenticating users to access the application running on azure.

some users are in active directory and some in sql azure database.
What i require is , when user access the application it must ask for credentials like user name and password.
Now this authentication is done using on premise active directory and sql azure.

This is very important kindly reply

Thank you

---

I created a project in which 'Default.aspx' was my home page

I referred to http://www.developerfusion.com/article/121561/integrating-active-directory-into-azure/ article for authenticating through active directory. It works like when a user enter my url a pop up show which ask's for user name and password which are checked in on-premise active directory.

After that i added a new page called 'login.aspx' in my project, with couple of text boxes and a login button to authenticate through sql azure table.This Table contains columns for name and password.I also created a check box here which will re-direct to 'Default.aspx' for the users, who exist in active directory.

I set Login.aspx as my home page.

when i run my project , still a popup for active directory authentication is showing automatically.

Please reply what to do ?

Comment: Why not [federate your identity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5505030/175679) using [ADFS/WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351) instead of synchronizing your AD information into SQL Azure?

Comment: All users record are not in active directory.

Comment: with ADFS/WIF , users stored in active directory will be able to access. Now the problem is some users data is in sql azure database.I want my application to authenticate users stored in Active directory and sql azure database.

Comment: it sounds like you need to build your own [STS (*Security Token Service*) provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748490.aspx) using WIF.

Comment: How to build my own sts provider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I point out in my previous reply, please put the login page in a folder that allows anonymous access:

To work around this, please create a sub folder to put your login page, and configure the sub folder to allow access from any users. For example, something like:

```
  <location
   path="loginfolder">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

The 'loginfolder' means the name of folder that contains the login page file.

> but When a user tries to Login from login form i.e forms auhentication
>   , Pop-up for windows authentication comes instead of redirecting to
>   Default.aspx

You can also check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx for more information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: This i have done , i am able to access loginfolder/Loginpage.aspx page , i meant was when i enter name and password  and click login button then instead of redirecting to Default.aspx i am again asked for authentication this time windows . Please tell me what to do now ?

Comment: "you can assign a role to him/her, so he/she's no longer anonymous and is allowed to view your site"                                     How to achieve this ?

Comment: I am doing this on loginpage.aspx which is in "loginfolder"
protected void Login1_Authenticate1(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            Boolean flag = false;
            flag = authenticateuser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);// This method checks name and pwd frm db.
            if (flag == true)
            {
                e.Authenticated = true;
                Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "~/Default.aspx";

            }
            else
                e.Authenticated = false;
        }
Pop-up shows even after entering correct user name and password.
Pls reply ?

Comment: Please assign the logged in user to a role, so he/she is no longer considered anonymous. You can refer to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx for a sample on how to use roles in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you have two authentication mechanisms, one is using Active Directory, and another one is using custom username/password? Actually, it would be better if we do not manually asking for users’ Active Directory credential in our own application. Otherwise, it will be stealing user’s Windows credential in our application. Please use built-in Windows authentication. In Windows Azure, we have two options. One is to federate with ADFS as pointed out by SilverNinja. The other is to use Windows Azure Connect to join our local domain, so we can use standard Windows authentication. I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433029.aspx for more information.

After that, we can provide a sign in option page that asks if the user wants to use Windows credential or the custom credential. When the user chooses Windows authentication, we can redirect the user to ADFS’s sign in page (or if the Azure instance has joined the local domain, the sign in progress will be transparent). If the user chooses custom credential, we can ask for username/password and then authenticate against SQL Azure.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WIF's Add STS Reference feature, it will generate a configuration file which requires you to sign in to the STS before using your web site. You can see something like this in your web.config:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

So if a user is not signed in to STS (in your case, ADFS), he/she will be unable to see any pages.

To work around this, please create a sub folder to put your login page, and configure the sub folder to allow access from any users. For example, something like:

```
  <location
   path="loginfolder">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

In the login page, you may want to first let the user choose between Windows authentication and custom authentication. Do not ask for user credentials yet. Once the user chooses Windows authentication, redirect the user to another page that's not under loginfolder. This will trigger normal WIF behavior that requires the user to sign in to STS. If the user chooses custom authentication, please display the login form, and after the user signs in, you can assign a role to him/her, so he/she's no longer anonymous and is allowed to view your site.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Xu Sir : I am just 1 step behind. I worked as per your solution , but When a user tries to Login from login form i.e forms auhentication , Pop-up for windows authentication comes instead of redirecting to Default.aspx. I am not able to authenticate my user through forms authentication.